# How can I change settings or version of embedded browser in windows7?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, activex

Programs like Winamp and SharpReader all use an embedded webbrowser that Windows provides for viewing webpages. By visiting sites like whatbrowser.org, the servers thinks it's internet explorer 8. I can't tell if this is ie9 in compatablity mode or not. And I can't seem to change settings for these browsers.

My question is how can I change the settings so it works as well as IE9? I more script error dialog boxes, and html5 doesn't work. But in IE9 they all work.

Just to be clear, this about ieframe, not add-ons inside of ie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the info needed here: [Web Browser Control – Specifying the IE Version](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version).

Good page on this exact issue; lots of good info.

Anyhow, there is a registry entry you can make to force the browser type (it's per-application).  I just tested with Winamp, and it worked like a charm.

For 32-bit:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

For 64-bit:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

Create a new DWORD value, and name it after the .EXE file with the embedded browser (ie: `winamp.exe`).

The value to set this key to is (taken from [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation)) as decimal values:

**9999 (0x270F)** 
 - Internet Explorer 9. Webpages are displayed in IE9 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.

**9000 (0x2328)**
 - Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode.

**8888 (0x22B8)**
 
 - Webpages are displayed in IE8 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.

**8000 (0x1F40)**
 - Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE8 mode.

**7000 (0x1B58)** 
 - Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode.

Winamp after adding the key (you don't even need to reboot or logout):

[image: Winamp's Browser using IE9]

Comment: This is great. I should check to see if there is a group policy setting that can set this for the whole office.